# Assertion error even if there is expected error in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Test in my app is throwing:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
```

Even if I have this:

```
@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
public void test(){
  // I can see from the console log that a java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't catching the exception? How are you logging it?

Comment: It is not enough for the exception to have been thrown at some point. The method `test` must complete abruptly due to the exception.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and it just shows there in the console

Comment: Yes there is a try-catch statement in the code that was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for JUnit to detect that an exception was thrown is for the `@Test` method to throw it, ie. terminate its execution because of it.

If you're catching the exception and handling, method execution won't stop because of a thrown exception. It will complete normally. You need it to complete abruptly because of the thrown exception. Rethrow it if you need to log it.

Answer (score 2):

By annotating your test with

```
@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
```

you are asserting that when the test is run, a RuntimeExcetption will be thrown and **not caught**.  The fact that you have stated in the comments that "*there is a try-catch statement in the code that was called*", implies that the exception is caught.

Thus JUnit is right to flag this as a failed test.  You are asserting that an exception is thrown, but one is not.